# Governator's lifecycle feature without calling Governator.createInjector

Tags: java, guice, governator

I want to use the lifecycle feature of Governator without calling `Governator.createInjector` because I already have some wrapper around my Guice injector and switching the two will be rather tricky.

[The documentation](https://github.com/Netflix/governator/tree/master/governator-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/governator), says the following:

> Governator provides a simple wrapper to Guice's Guice.createInjector through which lifecycle management is added.

Later, examples are given as alternatives to `awaitTermination()`, including in-injector possibilities.

This seems to indicate that I have the possibility to not use `Governator.createInjector` at all.

If this is true, how can I use Governator's lifecycle feature using only modules? Which modules do I have to load? `LifecycleModule` seems a no-brainer, but are there others?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Netflix/governator/blob/43328b9592f05b2c08508904acfe25b385f35b96/governator-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/governator/Governator.java#L58)'s the implementation.

Comment: Thank you. However given that I put a link at the source package folder, I believe it was rather obvious I already had a look at the source code somehow. Well... I did, and I don't want to go deep into the class graph to learn about every nook and cranny of Governor. I indeed saw that `LifecycleModule` is the only concrete module loaded, but what is the rest up to? Do I have to do anything? I think it's acceptable to read documentation to find out such answers. But code? No, I think it's too much, especially when it can be adapted rather quickly when the documentation is more static.

Comment: Well, the answer to your question doesn't seem to appear in the documentation, so I checked the source code.  It's only 40 lines.

Comment: Indeed, only 40 locs. With several governator-specific 40 locs dependencies with each other 40 governator-specifc locs dependencies with each other 40 governator-specifc locs dependencies. Hmmm, it starts to grow... maybe I should ask a question about it instead. If only some website was designed to ask such questions...